# Convergence question of Dirichlet's Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is an after-chapter exercise of Dirichlet's Test.

> Show that if the partial sum $S_n$ of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \leq Mn^r$, for some $r<1$, then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_k}{k}$ converges.

Comment: I am thinking about to show the ∑_(k=1)^∞▒a_k /k^r',where r<r'<1,is bounded, then by Dirichlet's Test, the original one is convergent. But I just can't work it out. Asking for help.

Comment: Some of your formatting has gone astray. Maybe a cut and paste issue. Maybe you can fix it. Regards

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are asking if the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_k}{k}$ is convergent assuming that the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ are bounded by $Mn^r$. Is that right? If yes you have to assume also that $a_n\geq0$ (why?):

From $\sum_{k=1}^na_k\leq Mn^r$ it follows that $\sum_{k=1}^na_k\lt Mn$ (since $r\lt1$). Therefore $\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{a_k}{n}\lt M, \ \forall n\in\mathbb N$. Now use that $\frac1n\lt\frac1k$ for all $k\gt n$ to conclude that the series  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_k}{k}$ is bounded...